# Resize shadowbox after it loads html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, shadowbox

im new to javascript and jQuery in general,

I have a html openened in Shadowbox with something like

```
<a href="idiomas.html" rel="shadowbox;height=300;width=470">Argentina</a>
```

Inside that html i have a link to another html that i want to display in the same shadowbox, but it's size is bigger.

How could i resize the shadowbox so that the second html it's not cutted off?

I've read something about

```
function openSB(path,width,height){
```

but i dont know how to make it work

Thanks

Comment: For reference: http://www.shadowbox-js.com/api.html

Comment: As i said, im new to jquery, i dont know how to apply this

Answer (score 0):

http://www.victorstanciu.ro/dynamically-resizing-the-shadowbox-js-modal-window/

"The reason you might want to manually resize the modal window is in case the content inside changes, for example in the case of IFrames. Fortunately, implementing such a method is quite easy."

You don't say what version you're using, but a comment on that page offers a solution for version 3 also: http://codestory.a-chantioux.fr/dynamic-resize-with-shadowbox-js/

Comment: "call the method" . Shadowbox window relative skin DynamicResize (1024, 768)...; 

Where do i do this?

Comment: Maybe a click handler on your inner link? Hard to say with so little to go on.

Comment: Thanks man, im new to jquery and javascript in general so i dont know how to do that exactly.

I have a simple inner link:

    <a href="idiomas2.html" >Idioma</a>